# Android ArrayAdapter is undefined

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm having trouble creating a Listview adapter, here's the code.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Recipes extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView recipelist = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recipe_drawer);

        String[] items ={ getResources().getString(R.string.block),
        getResources().getString(R.string.tool),
        getResources().getString(R.string.support),
        getResources().getString(R.string.veggie)
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Recipes.this, R.layout.recipes_list_item, items);
        recipelist.setAdapter(adapt);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes, container, false);
        return rootView;


    }

}
```

The error I get is in `ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Recipes.this, R.layout.recipes_list_item, items);` and it says

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(Recipes,int,String[]); is undefined.

I tried changing Recipes.this to just this and I still get the same error. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Recipes.this` to `getActivity()`. You are in a `Fragment`, which is not a `Context`, which is the first parameter to the `ArrayAdapter` family of constructors.

Comment: Tried it and it worked, I'm impressed at the speed of response. Just a minute after asking the question! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Recipes.this, R.layout.recipes_list_item, items);
```

By

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.recipes_list_item, items);
```

Use `getActivity` to get the activity context of the hosting activity

`public final Activity getActivity ()`

```
Added in API level 11
Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
```